# MacOS MS Word VBA - Force File name to Save as Bookmarked Text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm pretty new to this and am enjoying the challenge, but I've hit a bit of a wall.  I've created this word document form for staff to fill in.  When they fill in the fields of the form it auto updates fields at the top of the page to give it a unique title which has the agency name, client name and client reference number in it.  I want the file to then save with the title at the top of the page aptly named "filename".

This is what the document looks like:
[Page title and fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1zOe.png)

- Set text (which is always the same): "Call Recording Sheet - Council Tax"
- Beneath the set text are inserted REF fields that automatically update as the user fills in the table fields below.

Both lines of the title of the page are bookmarked as "filename"

I thought I'd try and put together code using forums etc, but I cannot get the filename to populate when I press save.  It just comes up with the first line "Call Recording Sheet -"

I have ZERO idea where I'm going wrong, but here is the code.  I'm wondering if it cannot read the auto fields?

```
Private Sub DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim bmRange As Range
    Dim bookmarkName As String
    Dim fileName As String

    ' Replace "YourBookmarkName" with the actual bookmark name
    bookmarkName = "filename"

    ' Check if the specified bookmark exists
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName) Then
        ' Set the range to the bookmark content
        Set bmRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range
        bmRange.Copy  ' Optional: Copy the content to the clipboard

        ' Get the bookmark content as the filename (remove illegal characters)
        fileName = Replace(bmRange.Text, "\", "_")
        fileName = Replace(fileName, "/", "_")
        fileName = Replace(fileName, ":", "_")
        fileName = Replace(fileName, "?", "_")
        fileName = Replace(fileName, Chr(34), "_")
        fileName = Replace(fileName, "<", "_")
        fileName = Replace(fileName, ">", "_")
        fileName = Replace(fileName, "|", "_")

        ' Save the document with the bookmark content as the filename
        If fileName <> "" Then
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 fileName:=fileName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
            ' Optional: Uncomment the line below to remove the bookmark after saving
            'ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Delete
        Else
            MsgBox "The bookmark content is empty or contains invalid characters.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "The specified bookmark does not exist.", vbExclamation, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help or signposting in the right direction would be most gratefully received!!

I've tried going on different forums to get better code examples, but cannot find anything.

I'm working on Office Mac, so am only using legacy form fields as office for mac doesn't seem to have the content control ones...

Answer (score 0):

The document title probably contains a return character **vbCr** or **Chr(13)**, a linefeed **vbLf** or **Chr(10)**, or a combination of the 2: **vbCrLf** or **Chr(13) & Chr(10)**. None of those are possible in a file name. You'll need to add those to your replace function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to work out from your example document what fields you are actually using, or whether you are actually using bookmarked areas as your code suggests.

Either way, unless you are using something like form fields, it's quite easy for the user to type *outside* the bookmark, so that the bookmark does not contain the text you expect (and could be blank). If you have bookmarked a whole table cell, then the bookmark's range.text will end with `Chr(13) & Chr(7)` (`Chr(7)` is an "end of cell" mark).

That said, you can use *some* Content Control features in Mac Word (as long as you're talking about a recent version, i.e. from the last 4 or 5 years I think. Mac Word does not provide any User Interface that allows you to insert them easily, so you either have to create the document elsewhere (e.g. Windows desktop Word) or use VBA to create them - for example

```
Sub addPlainTextCCAtSelection()
Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
Set cc = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText, Selection.Range)
With cc
  .Title = "Name"
  .Tag = "Name"
  .SetPlaceholderText Text:="Type Name Here"
  .LockContentControl = True
End With
Set cc = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can then retrieve text typed in the control using e.g.

```
Activedocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Text
```

(if you happen to know that the index number of the control is 1). You will retrieve the placeholder text if the user hasn't entered anything.

Or if you use unique Titles or Tags for your controls, you can use, say,

```
Activedocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Name")(1).Range.Text
```